# Tag for indigenous American languages?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to create a tag for the indigenous pre-Columbian languages of the Americas and their descendants. I don't quite know what to call it:

1. [american-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-languages)
2. [native-american-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-american-languages)
3. [indigenous-american-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indigenous-american-languages)
4. [american](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american)
5. [indigenous-american](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indigenous-american)
6. [american-indian-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-indian-languages)
7. [aboriginal-american-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aboriginal-american-languages)
8. [first-peoples](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-peoples)

Please let me know what you think would maximize correctness and minimize confusion and disrespect.

Comment: Which ones are we talking about? North? South? Both?

Comment: @Alenanno For tagging purposes I don't think that distinction is necessary. It's not really confusing or ambiguous. When we get more than a couple questions in the area maybe we can do that.

Comment: Don't forget Central! There's seven linguistically diverse countries that are niether North nor South: Belize, Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, and Panama. [Misumalpan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misumalpan_languages) is one language family that seems to be entirely within Central America only for instance.

Comment: The broadest label with its own page on Wikipedia seems to be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_languages_of_the_Americas

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, that's why I asked - that label is too long for a tag.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: I agree. I was going to suggest "mesoamerican languages" but that turned out not to cover South America. Since we're "experts" here I think we don't have to worry too much about "american languages" being taken the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hippietrail added [american-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-languages) which works for me.